# What precisely is the pairwise Fst calculated in GenAlEx 6.5?

Tags: molecular-genetics, population-genetics, fst

A professor of [population genetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_genetics) informed me that there is not a unique notion of [pairwise Fst](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34549777/) scores in the literature. This information has made me more cautious about what may be implemented by a given software package.

I am considering the GenAlEx Excel plugin ([Peakall & Smouse 2005](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1471-8286.2005.01155.x), [Peakall & Smouse 2012](https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/bts460)) for computing pairwise Fst scores. The [documentation](https://biology-assets.anu.edu.au/GenAlEx/Download_files/GenAlEx%206.5%20Guide.pdf) states

> Pairwise Fst : Outputs the pairwise Fst values between populations.
>
> - Output Pairwise Matrix: Outputs pairwise population statistics as a triangular Matrix.
>   Output is to worksheet `[NeiP]` for Nei’s Genetic Distance, to `[uNeiP]` for Nei’s
>   Unbiased Genetic Distance and to `[FstP]` for Pairwise Fst. This is in GenAlEx format
>   for further analyses if required.
> - Output Labeled Pairwise Matrix: Outputs pairwise population statistics as a labeled
>   triangular Matrix. Output is to worksheet `[NeiL]` for Nei’s Genetic Distance, to `[uNeiL]`
>   for Nei’s Unbiased Genetic Distance and to `[FstL]` for Pairwise Fst.
> - Output Pairwise Matrix as Table: Outputs pairwise population statistics as a table.
>   Output is to worksheet `[NeiT]` for Nei’s Genetic Distance, to `[uNeiT]` for Nei’s
>   Unbiased Genetic Distance and to `[FstT]` for Pairwise Fst.

I gather from this that `[NeiP]` is for a function called Nei's genetic distance, but the Wikipedia page on [genetic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_distance) suggests that there are multiple distance functions named after Nei. This also confuses me because I thought that these functions named after Nei were distinct from [fixation indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_index), and yet they are mentioned under this Pairwise Fst section in the documentation. I am similarly confused about the inclusion of `[uNeiL]` and `[NeiT]`.

And then there is the mentioning of `[FstP]`, `[FstL]`, and `[FstT]`. Clearly the `P`, `L`, and `T` correspond to whether the function returns a matrix, labeled pairwise matrix, or the same but as a table.

I've probably misunderstood the documentation, but I didn't understand why Nei's distance was mentioned. But in any case, what is GenAlEx 6.5 actually calculating (i.e. formula/model) if I use any of `[FstP]`, `[FstL]`, and `[FstT]`?

---

I have emailed the [authors](https://biology-assets.anu.edu.au/GenAlEx/Authors.html) of the GenAlEx6.5 package. I'll post an update if I get a response.

Comment: Nei's [original genetic distance](https://doi.org/10.1086/282771) was described in 1972 (paywall). He described the [unbiased calculation](https://doi.org/10.1093/genetics/89.3.583) in 1978.